# Delphi 7 Compiling components on every build

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, settings, delphi-7

I usually don't show compiler progress when compiling, but I decided to turn it on.

I noticed that when my program compiles, it is also compiling the components that it uses.  For example it uses Toolbar2000 (TB2K) and in the compiler progress window I can see it says compiling TB2kDock.pas, etc.

Is this by design?  Is there perhaps a setting where I can tell it not to compile components every time (Since they are not changing) and only compile what is in my program's actual source code directory?

Comment: As long as the .dcu files are found by the compiler, and the .pas files have not since been modified, they should not be recompiled. Is path where the dcu files go in your library path? Or are you perhaps choosing Build rather than Compile?

Comment: It does sound like the project's search paths are not set up correctly. The components' source folders are on the search path, but the pre-compiled package binaries folders are not, so the compiler is finding the .PAS source files instead of, or before, finding the DCU/BPx files.

Comment: I will go through the library path and make sure it all points to the right places. thanks

Comment: Check your IDE's Search Path settings too and make sure those are set up properly.  The directories on your library paths should only have `.dcu` files in them, not `.pas`.

Comment: And what should be in the search paths?

Comment: Okay I cleaned up all library paths so they point solely to .dcu files and not the .pas files for the components.  There were some .res files that it complained about not finding which were in source directories so i just pasted copies into the dcu directory so it would work.  Was there a better way for that? If i give it access to source it will recompile them again.

Comment: Yes, put the source dir in the path AFTER the dcu dir. That will ensure three things: 1) the dcu will be used; 2) the res files can be found without making copies; and 3) if a dcu happens to get deleted the source will be used (the dcu of which should end up in the source's folder unless you have a unit output path specified, then you should find it there)

Comment: Isn't there also a setting on packages "explicit rebuild" which prevents this? Not at IDE at the moment...

Comment: Runtime packages I presume?

Comment: @Jerry: The `explicit rebuild` has nothing to do with anything except packages, and that has nothing to do with your app's compilation unless you're building with runtime packages enabled. IOW, it has no impact on the question being asked here.

Comment: So are you suggesting that OP's components are not installed in a package? Packages may not be mentioned, but they may be there in this scenario.

Comment: In other words, @Chris, are these components installed in runtime packages?

Comment: Everything is just bundled into the final EXE, so i believe that means no to runtime packages.

Comment: usualyl it makes sense to run SysInternals Process Monitor and filter for file accesses of IDE or DCC executables. Then you cna see how build process is actually going and what is actually tried when compiler decides to rebuild files.

Answer (score 0):

Compile is supposed to just recompile your changed units and create new dcu files.  The linker always has to rebuild the Exe from the dcu files. Build recreates dcu files for all pas files whether you modified them or not.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What you say is correct but unfortunately does not answer the OP's question(s) as set out in his final para.

Answer (score -1):

before you look into this you have to understand that COMPILING your application and BUILDING it are two different things. As far as my understanding goes when you COMPILE the application Delphi modifies the exe and simply changes what you have changed in your applications code. When you BUILD the application it replaces the exe.

So when you build the application if will recompile all the units of the components that is listed in your settings and options, but when you just compile it (Even if it says its compiling that unit) its actually just searching for changed pieces of code in that unit that needs to be modified in your exe

I am speaking under correction of course

Comment: You're half right: Compile only searches for modified .pas files, but still has to relink the entire executable. It doesn't "modify the executable". Rebuild forces the compiler to compile every unit before linking.